# Listings all in the same style although different languages are defined and used

Tags: listings, lstlisting, lstdefinestyle

So I want to show some python, bash and terminal output using the listing package.

I searched for some language definitions for bash and python for the listing package and in the beginning it worked really good. Now I wanted to add some terminal output but I found that only the last defined language is used for all listings, no mather what language I manually define for the given listing.

I made up an basic example on overleaf:

https://www.overleaf.com/18688751pxczqpkbbkyg#/70340370/

Problem is, this example doesn't really gives the same result on overleaf as I am experiencing here on my local document.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to add some color highlighting for python and bash scripts and some blank code for the terminal output.

Edit: here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}

\begin{filecontents}{00_python.py}
# Image processing
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_dimensions = 224
# Image paths
train_dir = "/path/to/train"
validation_dir = "/path/to/train"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{00_terminal.txt}
test@ubuntu-vm:~/Desktop$ time ./00_preprocess_and_sort.sh
 Getting variables...Done

    input dir: /home/test/new/00_data/00_all
    sorted dir: /home/test/new/00_data/01_sorted
    backup dir (attr.): /home/test/new/00_data/00_all_backup_attributes
    backup dir: /home/test/new/00_data/00_all_backup
    id dir: /home/test/new/00_data/03_ids
    stats dir: /home/test/new/00_data/04_statistics
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{00_bash.sh}
#!/ bin/ bash

printf " Getting variables ... "
INPUT_DIR =~/ new /00 _data /00 _all
ID_DIR =~/ new /00 _data /03 _ids
SORTED_DIR =~/ new /00 _data /01 _sorted
BACKUP_DIR_ATTRIBUTES =~/ new /00 _data /00 _all_backup_attributes
BACKUP_DIR =~/ new /00 _data /00 _all_backup
STATISTIC_DIR =~/ new /00 _data /04 _statistics
\end{filecontents}

\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}

\lstset{language=python, 
        basicstyle=\itshape\small, 
        keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
        commentstyle=\color{comments},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\color{green},
        procnamekeys={def,class}
}

\lstset{language=bash,
        basicstyle=\bfseries,
        showstringspaces=false,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=bash, breaklines=true, title={Bash script}, frame=tb]{00_bash.sh}
\lstinputlisting[language=python, breaklines=true, title={Python code}, frame=tb]{00_python.py}
\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true, title={Terminal output}, frame=tb]{00_terminal.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\lstset` just sets the global `listings` options. That means that several `\lstset`s overwrite each other with the last one winning, furthermore their settings are overruled by local settings. I guess you want something like `\lstdefinestyle` (or maybe `\lstdefinelanguage`). (Also, please consider adding the code (in reduced form) directly to your question. Not all people like to follow links to third-party sites and you never know when that link becomes unreachable.)

Comment: Spooky ... just as I'm looking at the file somebody is editing it and changing between `\lstset` and `\lstdefinestyle`.

Comment: I am searching for a solution at the moment and it was me changing to lstdefinestyle but without giving me a proper solution as I wanted

Comment: Mhhh, then I don't quite understand what you want. To me it seems `\lstdefinestyle` works. Can you explain in more detail what you want, why and how `\lstdefinestyle` does not work and add a static version of the code that does not change to your question, please?

Comment: Ok I got it now with \lstdefinestyle. Somehow on overleaf the font highlighting is different from my local version. Thanks for your fast respose moewe :-)

Comment: Overleaf are running an older version of TeX live, I guess their `listings` is a bit outdated. Maybe some language definitions changed in the meantime, that could explain slight differences in highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As moewe already mentioned in the comments, I needed to change from `\lstset` (which changes the global listing settings) to `\lstdefinestyle` to create different styles.

So for example, from

```
\lstset{language=bash,
        basicstyle=\bfseries,
        showstringspaces=false,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
...
\lstinputlisting[language=bash, breaklines=true, title={Bash script}, frame=tb]{00_bash.sh}
```

to

```
\lstdefinestyle{bashstyle}{language=bash,
        basicstyle=\bfseries,
        showstringspaces=false,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
...
\lstinputlisting[style=bashstyle, breaklines=true, title={Bash script}, frame=tb]{00_bash.sh}
```